# AWS Lambda, On prem DB, /etc/host, ORA-12545

Tags: python, oracle, amazon-web-services

I setup a Lambda inside a VPC. I have two private subnets and i want to access a on prem DB, the security group has has all the inbound tcp connection for port 22 open, and all outbound open. Here is my lambda:

- Runtime: Python 2.7
- dependency: cx_Oracle 7.0.0
- Oracle Instant Client: instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-18.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
- Oracle Instant Client SDK: instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-18.3.0.0.0dbru.zip

  - Libaio libraries

Code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import os

host_file = '''
{} localhost
'''
with open('/tmp/HOSTALIASES', 'w') as hosts_file:
    hosts_file.write(host_file.format(os.uname()[1]))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('user_name/password@10.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/service_name
```

The file structure of my lambda look like this:

- access_db.py
- /lib
- cx_Oracle-7.0.0.dist-info
- cx_Oracle-doc
- cx_Oracle.so

/lib contain the oracle instant client + sdk + libaio

Using the same code, i am able to connect to the database from an EC2. ( same vpc, same private subnet, same setting on the security group ). I made the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ORACLE_HOME point to the lib folder. Now the ONLY difference i can see, is that on the EC2, i fill my /etc/host with my oracle DB IP alias, and if i remove them, i have the same error.

So i think the problem come from there. But on the lambda i try to use  /tmp/HOSTALIASES ( because it seem we can't edit /etc/hosts ) and it doesn't work. ( I also put an environment variable HOSTALIASES=/tmp/HOSTALIASES in my cloud formation.

Now i try to stop using /etc/host on my ec2 and copy all the content to /tmp/HOSTALIASES. But it fail, like in the lambda. Does somebody know how i can make this work? and why i need to fill my /etc/host file even if I use the IP of my database directly.

EDIT: The Oracle DB i am connecting to is in a cluster. So it's probably related to this : https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/community/oracle_database/3961128.html

Thanks!

Comment: oracle listener uses port 1521, check availability on port 1521  between the database and your host.

Comment: But, if i modify the /etc/host i can access the DB. How come? If the port were close it should never work? Am i missing something?

Comment: So, should we assume this is you? https://medium.com/@mitchplanck/aws-lambda-node-js-oracle-3b5806fbecd3  Wouldn't be bad to post your own answer here with a link to medium. And yes, THANK YOU!

Comment: @einarc Hey, it is not me. But this is good content, thanks sharing!

Comment: @Jbeat My pleasure.

Comment: For anyone looking. The link above works for subdomains only. HOSTALIASES do not support FQDN strings.